# Having an 'object' type extra member in a class will cause a lot of overhead c#?

Tags: c#, class, object, types, overhead

I have a big class hierarchy with a base class. To the base class, I want to add an 'object' type member for future use. The member is not used in most cases. Will it cause a big overhead?

```
abstract public class myBaseClass {
    protected object _furtherInfo = null;
    public object FurtherInfo {
        get { return _furtherInfo; }
        set { _furtherInfo = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: If it is null it will not take up a lot of space.  Only the size of the null pointer.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a question of overhead, but of design.  Adding a property to a base class that is not used by most inheritors is certainly a design smell.

Comment: Thanks, @jdweng. I forgot setting null by default.

Comment: @DavidL, the fact that it smells in design makes sense to me for sure, though having another member gives me many benefits to process data.

Comment: If it will only be used in some derived classes I would consider adding another class between the base class and the derived classes with this property.

Comment: @DavidL, by the way, there is a chance that the 'FurtherInfo' member can be used by any inheritors in the future. I didn't mean that the member won't be used at all by inheritors; actually, I am planning that the 'FurtherInfo' holds some info to process one of inheritors.

Comment: @ZoharPeled you got the exact point of mine. Yes, the member will be only be used in some derived classes, or it can be used by more inheritors in the future. However, I don't expect it to be used by most inherited classes.

Comment: Well, if you choose to add one more class to the chain of inheritance, you will have to change the base class for every class that will need to be using this property. If it's going to change a lot over time then perhaps just leave it in the base class. Perhaps it's not the best design, but it's easy for maitenance.

Comment: Yes, totally make sense. I will think about it a bit more...